# Getting error "internal_api_error_InvalidArgumentException"

Tags: mediawiki, visual-editor, parsoid

I'm having a problem setting up VisualEditor in internal MediaWiki.I installed Parsoid to view at localhost:8000.

I can see the edit and edit source in the wiki site, but when I try to edit I get this error "internal_api_error_InvalidArgumentException".

I can't find anything about this error and don't know how to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

First, enable debugging in your website so it can show you more information about the error by adding these lines to the localSettings.php file:

```
error_reporting( -1 );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
$wgShowSQLErrors = true;
$wgShowDBErrorBacktrace = true;
$wgDebugDumpSql = true;
```

After that, it should give you more details about this problem.

Also, if you don't have too many extensions in your website, try to disable all the extensions in your website, and test again.

This error seems to happen because of some conflict with other extensions, or because of some bad configurations of VisualEditor. So please test the two points above, and tell us what's going on.